# Am is supposed to include this syntax for browserify to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I am having problems importing `jquery.mustache.js` and `mustache` in my `browserify` set up. Could it be I have to use this syntax in the libraries themselves, in order to use them in my `app.js?`

jquery.mustache.js:

```
 exports.jQuery.Mustache = jQuery.Mustache;
```

and in mustache.js:

```
 exports.mustache = mustache;
```

This is my main/app.js file:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
var mixitup = require('./../bower_components/mixitup/build/jquery.mixitup.min.js');
var Mustache = require('./../bower_components/jquery-Mustache/jquery.mustache.js');
var mustache = require('mustache');
```

**UPDATE:**
Would up trying `browserify-shim` like Amadan mentioned,
But now I am getting the following error...

`[13:30:33] { [Error: Cannot find module 'jquery.mustache.js' from '/Users/avonproductsinc/Desktop/browserify_app/app/_js']`

I am including my `.json` file, although I ran it through a validator ;)

```
{
    "name": "browserify_app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "browserify app",

    "main": "./app/_js/app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
            "browser": {
            "mixitup": "./app/bower_components/mixitup/build/jquery.mixitup.min.js",
            "Mustache": "./app/bower_components/jquery-Mustache/jquery.mustache.js"
        },
        "browserify-shim": {
            "jquery": "$",
            "mixitup": {
                "exports": "mixitup",
                "depends": [
                    "jquery:jQuery"
                ]
            },
            "Mustache": {
                "exports": "Mustache",
                "depends": [
                    "jquery:jQuery",
                    "mustache:mustache"
                ]
            }
        },
        "author": "",
        "license": "ISC",
        "devDependencies": {
            "browser-sync": "^2.7.13",
            "browserify": "^11.1.0",
            "browserify-shim": "^3.8.10",
            "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
            "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
            "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
            "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
            "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
            "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
            "gulp-ruby-sass": "^1.0.0-alpha",
            "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
            "gulp-streamify": "^1.0.2",
            "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
            "gulp-useref": "^1.2.0",
            "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
            "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.2.0",
            "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
            "watchify": "^3.4.0"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "jquery": "^2.1.4",
            "mustache": "^2.1.3"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my path just for good measure!

[image: file path]

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: It is inconvenient changing libraries. Use browserify-shim if a library is not a proper node module - it will give it a wrapper that exports it properly.

Comment: @Lucio, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Mustache' of undefined`

Comment: No line indication? Then it most probably looks like jQuery is not being imported correctly on `jquery.mustache.js` so `jQuery` there is undefined and then you're trying use it with `jQuery.Mustache`. Try adding `var jQuery = require('jquery');` before the export in that file.

Comment: @Lucio - Thanks pal, but that didn't work. Maybe I'll look into the `browserify-shim`